How do we get a Riemann Tensor here?
I am studying zeroth law of thermodynamics of Black Holes and struggling with some concepts of differential geometry. Asking the following question here and not in physics stack exchange because my question is more about math.
The expression is :

$$\chi_{b}(\chi_{d} \nabla_{c}\nabla_{b}\chi_{a}-\chi_{c}\nabla_{d}\nabla_{b}\chi_{a})$$

How do we write the following?
$$\chi^b R_{ba}[{}_c{}^e \chi_{d}]\chi_{e}$$
I know that Riemann Tensor can be written in the following way :
$$\nabla_{a}\nabla_{b} A_{c}-\nabla_{b}\nabla_{a}A_{c}=R_{abc}^d A_{d}$$
but still I couldn't get my head around it.
